# Querying NCBI for genome version across different species using biopython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, ncbi

When reading an NCBI output from `base_entrez_fetch`, the genome version seems to be stored differently across various species.

For instance, in *Danio rerio*, it can be found under:

```
test = base_entrez_fetch('gene', gene_id, rettype='gb', retmode='xml', max_list_len=3000)

version = test[0][0]['Entrezgene_locus'][0]['Gene-commentary_heading']
```

However, that same indexing (`[0][0]['Entrezgene_locus'][0]['Gene-commentary_heading']`) does not return the genome version for a different species, such as *Homo sapiens*. I am working with various species, and I was wondering if there was a way to consistently retrieve the genome version across those species.